# Postfix / OpenDKIM config on Centos8

Tags: centos, postfix, opendkim

I've setup Postfix with Dovecot as an integrated mail service for my SaaS app, it worked great as an inbox. The issue started when I started to send emails, it was not signed so I went ahead and installed opendkim and configured it with Postfix, emails going out great signed no issues, but no

I broke the **inbound messages**. I cannot for the life of it figure out where I went wrong.

###### maillog:

```
May 30 22:12:30 dotcom postfix/smtpd[20436]: connect from mail-pj1-f43.google.com[209.85.216.43]
May 30 22:12:30 dotcom postfix/smtpd[20436]: discarding EHLO keywords: CHUNKING
May 30 22:12:31 dotcom postfix/smtpd[20436]: warning: SASL: Connect to smtpd failed: No such file or directory
May 30 22:12:31 dotcom postfix/smtpd[20436]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
May 30 22:12:32 dotcom postfix/master[19904]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 20436 exit status 1
```

###### postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 3h
milter_default_action = accept
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = dotsoft.co.za
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128, 129.232.230.173
myorigin = $mydomain
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dotcom.dotsoft.co.za/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dotcom.dotsoft.co.za/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

There is nothing in the dovecot log which is weird, see below extract from

##### dovecot -n:

```
# 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.18.0-383.el8.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS Stream release 8 xfs
# Hostname: dotcom.dotsoft.co.za
auth_mechanisms = plain login
first_valid_uid = 1000
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/
mail_privileged_group = mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster at dotcom.dotsoft.co.za
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/dotcom.dotsoft.co.za/fullchain.pem
ssl_cipher_list = PROFILE=SYSTEM
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the dovecot log which is weird, see below extract from dovecot - n:

Comment: dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-05-31 10:15:36 SAST; 8min ago
     Docs: man:dovecot(1)

Comment: There is only starup and stop logs see below: "May 31 10:15:35 master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=175907 uid=0 code=kill)
May 31 10:15:36 master: Info: Dovecot v2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a) starting up for imap, pop3, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the common configuration for dovecot, putting the socket at `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth`.

Since your SASL provider is Dovecot (`smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot`), Postfix is looking for a socket file in its chroot directory. You have to specify a *relative* path. This would usually be `smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth`.
But your configuration shows this as unchanged from default `smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd`, hence the error "Connect to smtpd failed". This could not have worked.

If that worked before.. compare against backups, or **check your `main.cf` file for deleted or mangled lines** around the `smtpd_sasl_*` settings. If there was an obvious syntax error in your `main.cf` file, Postfix would print a warning on startup, so a restart might help pinpoint.

---

Having auth-related problems disturb (non-authenticating) incoming mail **could have been avoided**, if you had set `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes` only for the services that need them, in `master.cf`, instead of globally in `main.cf`. Usually that would be below the service configurations for ports `smtps` or `submission`, as you will find in [common configuration recommendations](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/#using-sasl-with-postfix-submission-port).

Changing `unknown_hostname_reject_code` and similar settings is [explicitly advised against](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#unknown_hostname_reject_code) in Postfix documentation "unless you have a complete understanding of RFC 5321". Even if you do have a reason to change these for specific mail submissions, it is unlikely a good idea for receiving mail from the general internet.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I had an issue in my main.cf There were two lines that got merged into one: "milter_default_action = acceptsmtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
" I merely added a line break, and it's working now. Can't believe I missed that for hours.....